# get values from table by user_id from a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a look alike t twitter for studying purpose...
Now am I trying to create a query so the users can follow other users.

I have four tables - user , userdetails tweets and following.

The following table works with only three rows primary key ID , user_ID and following ID.
So the plan is that If I( user 1) calls following_id(2) I will get all the results from the table tweets where the messages gets stored with user_id.

But when Im calling the tables I only get outprinted two rows. by the user_id. and not grouped by message id.

this is my query that only gives me 2 results.

```
SELECT user.email, user.username, tweets.message, tweets.date, userdetails.profile_img, userdetails.firstname, userdetails.lastname, following.id, following.user_id, following.follow_id
FROM user
JOIN userdetails ON user.id = userdetails.user_id
JOIN tweets ON userdetails.user_id = tweets.user_id
JOIN following ON tweets.id = following.follow_id
GROUP BY tweets.message
```

Table structure.

```
    Following
    id | user_id | follow_id

    Tweets
    user_id|id|date|message

    user
    id|email|password|username

    userdetails
    id|firstname|lastname|profile_img|user_id|about
```

But the out print here become

```
email|username | message | date |profile_img |firstname |lastname |id |user_id
1. email 1...username message date......
2 .email 2........username message date.....
```

idea ? Or Am i thinking wrong with the table following ?

Comment: shouldn't it supposed to be `tweets.user_id = following.follow_id`?

Comment: Yes, If I removed the group and did as you said. It worked like a charm. thanks

Comment: @didierc you should mark the comment as answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close to the right query: just replace

```
 tweets.id = following.follow_id
```

with

```
 tweets.user_id = following.follow_id
```